# Why is it impossible to use a variable with `to`, in Scala?

Tags: scala, collections, range

The following doesn't compile :

```
var id_last_pivot : Integer = 0
(id_last_pivot to content.length).maxBy(...
```

The reported error is : "Cannot resolve symbol to"

If I replace `id_last_pivot` by a number value, it works.

Why ? How to get around this problem ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The class `Integer` is from the `java` which wraps the value of primitive type in an object and there is no any method `to` in it

You need to use `Int` from the package `scala.Int` to use the method `to`

```
var id_last_pivot : Int = 0
```

Now you can use the method as `(id_last_pivot to content.length)`

> There is an implicit conversion from `[[scala.Int]]` =>
>   `[[scala.runtime.RichInt]]`  which provides useful non-primitive
>   operations.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If the type `java.lang.Integer` of the variable `id_last_pivot` is not under your control, you can also use type ascription

```
((id_last_pivot: Int) to content.length).maxBy(
```

instead of introducing a separate variable.